# Goodness of fit test for a mixture in R

Tags: r, normal-distribution, goodness-of-fit, mixture-distribution

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Goodness of fit test for a mixture in R](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/28873/goodness-of-fit-test-for-a-mixture-in-r)

I just estimated the parameters for a mixture of two gaussians with different means and different sigmas, I would like to test if the data adjusts well to the explicit form of the mixture, do I necessarily need to simulate data from the mixture or how can I test the goodness of fit using in one hand the data and the other the explicit mixture with the estimated parameters? I am using the mixtools package.