# KS-statistic decile seperation - significance?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, predictive-models, random-forest, kolmogorov-smirnov-test

I already referred the posts [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/323711/interpret-the-ks-test) and [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/514341/how-to-interpret-ks-statistic-and-p-value-form-scipy-ks-2samp) but they are different and doesn't answer my problem.

I am currently working on a binary classification problem with random forests, neural networks etc.

During assessment of the model, I generated the below KS-statistic

[image]

While I understand that KS-statistic indicates the seperation power between both classes,

a) what does it mean to high seperation in Decile 1 vs 2  vs 5 or 8? and What is a good value for KS-statistic?

Comment: So you compute a KS statistic for each model and then want to use this to decide which model is the best?

Comment: @frank - Doesn't it make sense to use KS-statistic for a single model? I built lift, gain and KS-statistic for a single model. No multiple model comparsion. As my dataset is imbalanced, I thought of using these approaches to assess my model performance

Comment: This is the related post - if you want more info about my problem - https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/567964/discriminatory-model-but-no-discriminatory-features