# Fitting mixture distributions and computing goodness-of-fit?

Tags: r, distributions, goodness-of-fit, mixture-distribution

This question is a follow-up from a previous question of mine [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/58220/what-distribution-does-my-data-follow/58241#comment111936_58241). Thanks to @Glen_b, @gung and @rbatt for teaching me so many new things yesterday. It was mentioned in passing that mixture distributions might be a possibility so I figured I will learn about these.

I have seen [some](http://exploringdatablog.blogspot.com/2011/08/fitting-mixture-distributions-with-r.html) [articles](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/28873/goodness-of-fit-test-for-a-mixture-in-r) on how to fit mixture distributions to data and they seem very interesting. To fit two lognormals to my data, I did the following:

```
library(mixtools)

x <- c(1528L, 285L, 87138L, 302L, 115L, 416L, 8940L, 19438L, 165820L, 540L, 1653L, 1527L, 974L, 12999L, 226L, 190L, 306L, 189L, 138542L, 3049L, 129067L, 21806L, 456L, 22745L, 198L, 44568L, 29355L, 17163L, 294L, 4218L, 3672L, 10100L, 290L, 8341L, 128L, 11263L, 1495243L, 1699L, 247L, 249L, 300L, 351L, 608L, 186684L, 524026L, 1392L, 396L, 298L, 1063L, 11102L, 6684L, 6546L, 289L, 465L, 261L, 175L, 356L, 61652L, 236L, 74795L, 64982L, 294L, 95221L, 322L, 38892L, 2146L, 59347L, 2118L, 310801L, 277964L, 205679L, 5980L, 66102L, 36495L, 580277L, 27600L, 509L, 21795L, 21795L, 301L, 617L, 331L, 250L, 123501L, 144L, 347L, 121443L, 211L, 232L, 445783L, 9715L, 10308L, 1921L, 178L, 168L, 291L, 6915L, 6735L, 1008478L, 274L, 20L, 3287L, 591208L, 797L, 586L, 170613L, 938L, 3121L, 249L, 1497L, 24L, 1407L, 1217L, 1323L, 272L, 443L, 49466L, 323L, 323L, 784L, 900L, 26814L, 2452L, 214713L, 3668L, 325L, 20439L, 12304L, 261L, 137L, 379L, 2273L, 274L, 17760L, 920699L, 13L, 485644L, 1243L, 226L, 20388L, 584L, 17695L, 1477L, 242L, 280L, 253L, 17964L, 7073L, 308L, 260692L, 155L, 58136L, 16644L, 29353L, 543L, 276L, 2328L, 254L, 1392L, 272L, 480L, 219L, 60L, 2285L, 2676L, 256L, 234L, 1240L, 219714L, 102174L, 258L, 266L, 33043L, 530L, 6334L, 94047L, 293L, 536L, 48557L, 4141L, 39079L, 23259L, 2235L, 17673L, 28268L, 112L, 64824L, 127992L, 5291L, 51693L, 762L, 1070735L, 179L, 189L, 157L, 157L, 122L, 1045L, 1317L, 186L, 57901L, 456126L, 674L, 2375L, 1782L, 257L, 23L, 248L, 216L, 114L, 11662L, 107890L, 203022L, 513L, 2549L, 146L, 53331L, 1690L, 10752L, 1648611L, 148L, 611L, 198L, 443L, 10061L, 720L, 10L, 24L, 220L, 38L, 453L, 10066L, 115774L, 97713L, 7234L, 773L, 90154L, 151L, 1560L, 222L, 51558L, 214L, 948L, 208L, 1127L, 221L, 169L, 1528L, 78959L, 61566L, 88049L, 780L, 6196L, 633L, 214L, 2547L, 19088L, 119L, 561L, 112L, 17557L, 101086L, 244L, 257L, 94483L, 6189L, 236L, 248L, 966L, 117L, 333L, 278L, 553L, 568L, 356L, 731L, 25258L, 127931L, 7735L, 112717L, 395L, 12960L, 11383L, 16L, 229067L, 259076L, 311L, 366L, 2696L, 7265L, 259076L, 3551L, 7782L, 4256L, 87121L, 4971L, 4706L, 245L, 34457L, 4971L, 4706L, 245L, 34457L, 258L, 36071L, 301L, 2214L, 2231L, 247L, 537L, 301L, 2214L, 230L, 1076L, 1881L, 266L, 4371L, 88304L, 50056L, 50056L, 232L, 186336L, 48200L, 112L, 48200L, 48200L, 6236L, 82158L, 6236L, 82158L, 1331L, 713L, 89106L, 46315L, 220L, 5634L, 170601L, 588L, 1063L, 2282L, 247L, 804L, 125L, 5507L, 1271L, 2567L, 441L, 6623L, 64781L, 1545L, 240L, 2921L, 777L, 697L, 2018L, 24064L, 199L, 183L, 297L, 9010L, 16304L, 930L, 6522L, 5717L, 17L, 20L, 364418L, 58246L, 7976L, 304L, 4814L, 307L, 487L, 292016L, 6972L, 15L, 40922L, 471L, 2342L, 2248L, 23L, 2434L, 23342L, 807L, 21L, 345568L, 324L, 188L, 184L, 191L, 188L, 198L, 195L, 187L, 185L, 33968L, 1375L, 121L, 56872L, 35970L, 929L, 151L, 5526L, 156L, 2687L, 4870L, 26939L, 180L, 14623L, 265L, 261L, 30501L, 5435L, 9849L, 5496L, 1753L, 847L, 265L, 280L, 1840L, 1107L, 2174L, 18907L, 14762L, 3450L, 9648L, 1080L, 45L, 6453L, 136351L, 521L, 715L, 668L, 14550L, 1381L, 13294L, 13100L, 6354L, 6319L, 84837L, 84726L, 84702L, 2126L, 36L, 572L, 1448L, 215L, 12L, 7105L, 758L, 4694L, 29369L, 7579L, 709L, 121L, 781L, 1391L, 2166L, 160403L, 674L, 1933L, 320L, 1628L, 2346L, 2955L, 204852L, 206277L, 2408L, 2162L, 312L, 280L, 243L, 84050L, 830L, 290L, 10490L, 119392L, 182960L, 261791L, 92L, 415L, 144L, 2006L, 1172L, 1886L, 233L, 36123L, 7855L, 554L, 234L, 2292L, 21L, 132L, 142L, 3848L, 3847L, 3965L, 3431L, 2465L, 1717L, 3952L, 854L, 854L, 834L, 14608L, 172L, 7885L, 75303L, 535L, 443347L, 5478L, 782L, 9066L, 6733L, 568L, 611L, 533L, 1022L, 334L, 21628L, 295362L, 34L, 486L, 279L, 2530L, 504L, 525L, 367L, 293L, 258L, 1854L, 209L, 152L, 1139L, 398L, 3275L, 284178L, 284127L, 826L, 751L, 1814L, 398L, 1517L, 255L, 13745L, 43L, 1463L, 385L, 64L, 5279L, 885L, 1193L, 190L, 451L, 1093L, 322L, 453L, 680L, 452L, 677L, 295L, 120L, 12184L, 250L, 1165L, 476L, 211L, 4437L, 7310L, 778L, 260L, 855L, 353L, 97L, 34L, 87L, 137L, 101L, 416L, 130L, 148L, 832L, 187L, 291L, 4050L, 14569L, 271L, 1968L, 6553L, 2535L, 227L, 202L, 647L, 266L, 2681L, 106L, 158L, 257L, 234L, 1726L, 34L, 465L, 436L, 245L, 245L, 2790L, 104L, 1283L, 44416L, 142L, 13617L, 232L, 171L, 221L, 719L, 176L, 5838L, 37488L, 12214L, 3780L, 5556L, 5368L, 106L, 246L, 101L, 158L, 10743L, 5L, 46478L, 5286L, 9866L, 32593L, 174L, 298L, 19617L, 19350L, 230L, 78449L, 78414L, 78413L, 78413L, 6260L, 6260L, 209L, 2552L, 522L, 178L, 140L, 173046L, 299L, 265L, 132360L, 132252L, 4821L, 4755L, 197L, 567L, 113L, 30314L, 7006L, 10L, 30L, 55281L, 8263L, 8244L, 8142L, 568L, 1592L, 1750L, 628L, 60304L, 212553L, 51393L, 222L, 13471L, 3423L, 306L, 325L, 2650L, 74796L, 37807L, 103751L, 6924L, 6727L, 667L, 657L, 752L, 546L, 1860L, 230L, 217L, 1422L, 347L, 341055L, 4510L, 4398L, 179670L, 796L, 1210L, 2579L, 250L, 273L, 407L, 192049L, 236L, 96084L, 5808L, 7546L, 10646L, 197L, 188L, 19L, 167877L, 200509L, 429L, 632L, 495L, 471L, 2578L, 251L, 198L, 175L, 19161L, 289L, 20718L, 201L, 937L, 283L, 4829L, 4776L, 5949L, 856907L, 2747L, 2761L, 3150L, 3142L, 68031L, 187666L, 255211L, 255231L, 6581L, 392991L, 858L, 115L, 141L, 85629L, 125433L, 6850L, 6684L, 23L, 529L, 562L, 216L, 1450L, 838L, 3335L, 1446L, 178L, 130101L, 239L, 1838L, 286L, 289L, 68974L, 757L, 764L, 218L, 207L, 3485L, 16597L, 236L, 1387L, 2121L, 2122L, 957L, 199899L, 409803L, 367877L, 1650L, 116710L, 5662L, 12497L, 613889L, 10182L, 260L, 9654L, 422947L, 294L, 284L, 996L, 1444L, 2373L, 308L, 1522L, 288L, 937L, 291L, 93L, 17629L, 5151L, 184L, 161L, 3273L, 1090L, 179840L, 1294L, 922L, 826L, 725L, 252L, 715L, 6116L, 259L, 6171L, 198L, 5610L, 5679L, 862L, 332L, 1324L, 536L, 98737L, 316L, 5608L, 5526L, 404L, 255L, 251L, 14067L, 3360L, 3623L, 8920L, 288L, 447L, 453L, 1604687L, 115L, 127L, 127L, 2398L, 2396L, 2396L, 2398L, 2396L, 2397L, 154L, 154L, 154L, 154L, 887L, 636L, 227L, 227L, 354L, 7150L, 30227L, 546013L, 545979L, 251L, 171647L, 252L, 583L, 593L, 10222L, 2660L, 1864L, 2884L, 1577L, 1304L, 337L, 2642L, 2462L, 280L, 284L, 3463L, 288L, 288L, 540L, 287L, 526L, 721L, 1015L, 74071L, 6338L, 1590L, 582L, 765L, 291L, 983L, 158L, 625L, 581L, 350L, 6896L, 13567L, 20261L, 4781L, 1025L, 722L, 721L, 1618L, 1799L, 987L, 6373L, 733L, 5648L, 987L, 1010L, 985L, 920L, 920L, 4696L, 1154L, 1132L, 927L, 4546L, 692L, 702L, 301L, 305L, 316L, 313L, 801L, 788L, 14624L, 14624L, 9778L, 9778L, 9778L, 9778L, 757L, 275L, 1480L, 610L, 68495L, 1152L, 1155L, 323L, 312L, 303L, 298L, 1641L, 1607L, 1645L, 616L, 1002L, 1034L, 1022L, 1030L, 1030L, 1027L, 1027L, 934L, 960L, 47L, 44L, 1935L, 1925L, 43L, 47L, 1933L, 1898L, 938L, 830L, 286L, 287L, 807L, 807L, 741L, 628L, 482L, 500L, 480L, 431L, 287L, 298L, 227L, 968L, 961L, 943L, 932L, 704L, 420L, 548L, 3612L, 1723L, 780L, 337L, 780L, 527L, 528L, 499L, 679L, 308L, 1104L, 314L, 1607L, 990L, 1156L, 562L, 299L, 16L, 20L, 287L, 581L, 1710L, 1859L, 988L, 962L, 834L, 1138L, 363L, 294L, 2678L, 362L, 539L, 295L, 996L, 977L, 988L, 39L, 762L, 579L, 595L, 405L, 1001L, 1002L, 555L, 1102L, 54L, 1283L, 347L, 1384L, 603L, 307L, 306L, 302L, 302L, 288L, 288L, 286L, 292L, 529L, 56844L, 1986L, 503L, 751L, 3977L, 367L, 4817L, 4631L, 4609L, 4579L, 937L, 402L, 257L, 570L, 1156L, 3297L, 3948L, 4527L, 3119L, 15227L, 3893L, 538L, 802L, 5128L, 595L, 522L, 1346L, 449L, 443L, 323L, 372L, 369L, 307L, 246L, 260L, 342L, 283L, 963L, 751L, 108L, 280L, 320L, 287L, 285L, 283L, 529L, 536L, 298L, 29427L, 29413L, 761L, 249L, 255L, 304L, 297L, 256L, 119L, 288L, 564L, 234L, 226L, 530L, 766L, 223L, 5858L, 5568L, 481L, 462L, 8692L, 498L, 330L, 7604L, 15L, 121738L, 121833L, 826L, 760L, 208937L, 1598L, 1166L, 446L, 85598L, 513L, 84897L, 50239L, 308L, 1351L, 283L, 7100L, 7101L, 321L, 1019L, 287L, 253L, 634L, 629L, 628L, 678L, 1391L, 1147L, 853L, 287L, 1174L, 287L, 197145L, 197116L, 147L, 147L, 712L, 274L, 283L, 907L, 434L, 1164L, 30L, 599L, 577L, 315L, 1423L, 1250L, 30L, 1502L, 296L, 348L, 617L, 339L, 328L, 123L, 338L, 332L, 47133L, 288L, 340L, 1524L, 1049L, 1072L, 1031L, 1059L, 1038L, 989L, 52L, 54L, 986L, 46L, 1202L, 1272L, 43L, 785L, 761L, 16924L, 289L, 264L, 453L, 365L, 356L, 280L, 16520L, 281L, 255L, 244L, 642L, 1003L, 951L, 921L, 1011L, 45L, 932L, 973L, 39L, 40L, 159L, 566L, 49L, 1161L, 50L, 200L, 215L, 361L, 377L, 980L, 935L, 882L, 281L, 280L, 1025L, 319L, 690L, 284L, 271L, 276L, 286L, 371L, 324L, 304L, 311L, 341L, 603L, 11566L, 270L, 286L, 342L, 326L, 11018L, 282L, 271L, 286L, 586L, 604L, 750L, 608L, 523L, 506L, 3303L, 1079797L, 1079811L, 530L, 2631L, 882L, 628L, 30L, 11905L, 12966L, 390995L, 322353L, 1763L, 1755L, 709L, 713L, 365L, 351L, 205L, 393L, 284L, 39417L, 320L, 322L, 8039L, 995L, 625L, 785L, 298L, 518L, 467L, 1050L, 329L, 141345L, 55566L, 40318L, 287L, 220L, 309346L, 220L, 215314L, 304L, 296L, 4301L, 4311L, 1543L, 1549L, 2876L, 2894L, 287L, 290L, 215L, 605L, 577L, 254L, 1330L, 1863L, 140L, 328L, 284L, 291L, 283L, 1701L, 1696L, 519L, 499L, 2440007L, 289L, 294L, 311L, 324L, 4793L, 4808L, 249L, 205L, 219L, 638L, 2653L, 2648L, 351L, 323L, 1056L, 327L, 794L, 1491L, 284L, 289L, 220L, 765L, 565L, 808L, 832L, 772L, 41668L, 42307L, 6843L, 6612L, 6598L, 241164L, 531L, 554L, 1246L, 459L, 971504L, 805L, 2615L, 2290L, 2086L, 2063L, 2685L, 2704L, 275L, 461L, 458L, 317L, 889L, 335L, 974L, 959L, 253142L, 257L, 250L, 282L, 293L, 666L, 4991L, 287L, 588L, 555L, 3585L, 3195L, 481L, 2405L, 135266L, 571L, 1805L, 365L, 340L, 232L, 224L, 298L, 3682L, 3677L, 577L, 571L, 288L, 297L, 293L, 291L, 256L, 214L, 1257L, 1271L, 65471L, 65471L, 65476L, 65476L, 4680L, 4675L, 339L, 329L, 284L, 288L, 4859L, 4851L, 2534L, 24222L, 330684L, 330684L, 2116L, 282L, 412L, 429L, 2324L, 1978L, 502L, 286L, 943149L, 256L, 288L, 286L, 1098L, 1125L, 442L, 240L, 182L, 2617L, 1068L, 25204L, 170L, 418L, 1867L, 8989L, 1804L, 1240L, 6610L, 1237L, 1750L, 1565L, 1565L, 3662L, 1803L, 218L, 172L, 780L, 1418L, 2390L, 7514L, 23214L, 1464L, 1060L, 1503L, 308802L, 308357L, 21691L, 298817L, 289875L, 4442L, 289284L, 235L, 456L, 676L, 897L, 289109L, 1865L, 288030L, 287899L, 287767L, 287635L, 286639L, 286509L, 286157L, 1427L, 2958L, 4340L, 5646L, 282469L, 7016L, 279353L, 278568L, 316L, 558L, 3501L, 1630L, 278443L, 1360L, 828L, 1089L, 278430L, 278299L, 278169L, 278035L, 277671L, 277541L, 277400L, 277277L, 276567L, 285L, 555L, 834L, 1084L, 1355L, 5249L, 14776L, 1441L, 755L, 755L, 70418L, 3135L, 1026L, 1497L, 949663L, 68L, 526058L, 1692L, 150L, 48370L, 4207L, 4088L, 197551L, 197109L, 196891L, 196634L, 2960L, 194319L, 194037L, 3008L, 3927L, 178762L, 178567L, 403L, 178124L, 2590L, 177405L, 177179L, 301L, 328L, 390685L, 390683L, 575L, 1049L, 819L, 367L, 289L, 277L, 390L, 301L, 318L, 3806L, 3778L, 3699L, 3691L)

mixmdl = normalmixEM(log(x), k=2, epsilon = 1e-08, maxit = 1000, maxrestarts=20, 
                     verb = TRUE, fast=FALSE, ECM = FALSE, arbmean = TRUE, arbvar = TRUE)

plot(mixmdl, which=2))
lines(density(log(x)), lty=2,lwd=2)
```

And, the result looks like this, which seems decent enough visually:

[image]

I was wondering how I can test the goodness-of-fit for this mixture. I was looking into the approach outlined [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/28873/goodness-of-fit-test-for-a-mixture-in-r) by jbowman but I am unable to get it to work. I changed `pnorm` to `plnorm` because I am testing `lognormal` here in my case.

```
pmlnorm <- function(x, meanlog, sdlog, pmix) {
  pmix[1]*plnorm(x,meanlog[1],sdlog[1]) + (1-pmix[1])*plnorm(x,meanlog[2],sdlog[2])
}

ks.test(log(x), pmlnorm, meanlog=mixmdl$mu, sdlog=mixmdl$sigma, pmix=mixmdl$lambda)

One-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test

data:  log(x) 
D = 0.9987, p-value < 2.2e-16
alternative hypothesis: two-sided 

Warning message:
In ks.test(log(x), pmlnorm, meanlog = mixmdl$mu, sdlog = mixmdl$sigma,  :
  ties should not be present for the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test
```

I think I am doing something fundamentally wrong or maybe these are the actual values. Can someone help me out?

Comment: I'm glad to see you're continuing on from this post : http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/58220/what-distribution-does-my-data-follow/58241#comment111936_58241 !

Comment: @rbatt: +1 Yes. I am interested in learning more about this topic from a practical perspective and thought this really is a very different topic so I'm posting it as a new question. I am doing some reading but due to my lack of experience, I don't want to use these techniques incorrectly. :) I'll add a cross-reference to the previous question. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Remove the log() wrapper in ks.test(). You tried to test the distance between a normal and lognormal distributions.

Answer (score 3):

Mixture modelling in my experience can be tricky. Getting a good fit from a mixture model can be much more difficult than realising that a mixture may be a good approach.

I have to say that I don't find the fit convincing here. Your graphics alone do not give much support to your summary of "decent".

Kernel density estimates do give some support to the idea of two modes. (That is, using the default choice of your software, as the second mode disappears readily if you smooth enough.)  The first mode is about log(x) = 6. The second is about log(x) = 12, but is however much weaker. The density at the first mode is higher by a factor of about 4 or 5, again at or near default choices of kernel type and width. On your graph, the kernel density is the dashed line, but as you show it it has been truncated: the density rises to more than 0.25 if smoothed similarly to what you did. (I used different software, but that should be immaterial.)

In fact a complete curve can be seen at [What distribution does my data follow?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/58220/what-distribution-does-my-data-follow/)

In contrast the mixture model yields two modes with more nearly equal density and the position of the second fitted mode does not correspond well to the observed secondary mode, being higher at about log(x) = 14. Furthermore, in each case the density of the other distribution is negligible at the position of the mode, so the ratio of densities at the two modes would be about the same in the combined distribution. (It isn't expected that modes of fitted components correspond exactly to modes in the data, but the mismatch here is disappointing.)

The histogram here is a mystery. With this number of data (1567 observations) you could afford more bins than 9. But what is the histogram showing? If it's showing the combined fitted mixture model, that should be a smooth curve; if it's showing the original data, it's not doing a good job.

That said, what is currently holding you up? The error message from the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test function indicates that it objects to ties, and as you do have ties in your data, that seems right. But, as I have discussed, the graphics alone tell you that the fit is not good. Wanting a P-value too would just be icing an unwelcome cake.

A more convincing fit therefore might require the distribution with the higher mode to be a much smaller fraction of the total, but I don't have good ideas on how to move in that direction.

Alternatively, many real distributions don't approximate theoretical distributions (or even mixtures of them) at all well. It's always welcome when that happens, but it can be fine just to present smoothed density estimates and say "This is what we have". Even in cases where we think we have two distinct sub-populations (say height or weight for males or females), it can be really hard to see that from a combined distribution.

(Incidentally, for the sake of many readers, please do not use both red and green curves in a graph.)

Comment: +1 Thank you very much for your time. Can you also comment on the bootstrap technique explained in the post here: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/28873/goodness-of-fit-test-for-a-mixture-in-r When I tried this approach, I got a 0.111 p-value. I don't quite understand whether it is fair to use the bootstrap approach in the first place.  About the red/green curves - point taken. R base did something weird there. Thank you.

Comment: No precise comment from me on that, sorry. I guess you'd need to explain in much more detail what you did and what you want to know. A comment can't encapsulate a new question. But I don't understand enthusiasm for K-S test here. It can't tell you what is right about a fit and what is wrong.

Comment: Fair enough. I am not expecting a reply but I'll add one additional point anyways. The OP in that post initially gets a high p-value but later suggests a bootstrap technique that results in a lower p-value. I wasn't quite understanding which technique to follow. As for the K-S test, I'm not bent on using this. I am just looking to see if there is a clear way for a non-statistician to tell someone help that this fit is good or bad.

Comment: The burden of my answer is that graphics show you when the approach is or isn't working, but they must be used critically. Success is not guaranteed in mixture modelling.

Answer (score 2):

Assessing the goodness of a fit of a model requires specifying the cost of the model choice and the reward of the model fit. Usually, these decisions cannot be made from the data alone, and require more from the context of how the model is to be used. To see why cost the model choice is important, you could put a delta function with weight 1/n at each data point and get perfect recapitulation, but the model would be no more useful then just having the data in the first place. The point of the model is to somehow summarize the data into a more useful form.

Once the cost has been specified, it is clear that the model can't (and shouldn't!) represent all aspects of the data. One way to think of the reward function for model fit is to indicate which aspects of the data are important to model. In general different choices will bring out different aspects of the data, so that a given set of models may be ranked differently under different reward functions.

Here are a few popular reward functions for model fit:

- [Kullback-Leibler divergence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullback%E2%80%93Leibler_divergence)
- [Anderson-Darling test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anderson%E2%80%93Darling_test) (generally preferred over the K-S test)
- [Energy Distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Energy_distance)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not certain how the package you are using creates the fit, but if you have a closed form for the mixture (5 parameters, the mixing percentage $p$ and the meanlog and sdlog of the two lognormals) what you can do is generate $\lfloor{(\textrm{a large number like } 10^7)\cdot p}\rfloor$ samples from lognormal A and the remainder from the other, pool them together to create one huge sample, and use the pooled sample's empirical CDF as an estimate of the "theoretical" CDF of the mixed lognormal, and then run a K-S, Cramer-von-Mises (my poison of choice) or Anderson-Darling test on the data against it.

As for the actual fitting, I tend to use maximum likelihood, where the likelihood of each data point is $p\cdot f_1(x) + (1-p)\cdot f_2(x)$.